# Redirecting a URL using nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have the following configuration in a linux nginx reverse proxy setup. All is working fine for the basic redirection. What I want to achieve is a rewrite from webmail.someserver.net to webmail.someserver.net/gw

I can't seem to get any rewrite rule to achieve this successfully and I'm probably missing something very simple. Can anyone provide any ideas?
Thanks

```
server {
        listen       80;
    server_name  webmail.someserver.net;
    access_log  /var/log/www/webmail.someserver.net.access.log;  
    error_log  /var/log/www/webmail.someserver.net.error.log error; 
        rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;    # force redirect http to https
    index  index.html index.htm;  
    }
    server {
        listen 443;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/servercerts/someserver.net.chained.crt;        # path to your cacert.pem
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/servercerts/certified_wildcard_certificate_Private.key;    # path to your privkey.pem
        server_name webmail.someserver.net;                    #Domain Name
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
#   rewrite ^ $scheme://$host/gw redirect;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";
        server_tokens off;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://ebvl-009.cdn.someserver.net;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to redirect `/` to `/gw` use:

```
location = / {
    return 301 /gw;
}
```

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return) for more details.

As an aside, your statement `rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;` can also be written more simply as: `return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, What I had missed was the use of multiple location blocks. Added your suggested block in full as a separate block has solved the problem. Sometimes you just can see for looking. Much appreciated.